# template overload not found

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, overloading, template-specialization

I'm trying to understand why in the following code the assertion fails.

```
// file dconvert.h
struct A{};
struct B{int n;};
struct C{double cc;};

template<class FromStruct, class ToStruct>
void dconvert(FromStruct from, ToStruct to)
  {
  struct Placeholder {FromStruct f;};
  static_assert(std::is_same<Placeholder, FromStruct>::value, "CONVERSION NOT DEFINED");
  }

template<class FromStruct>
void dconvert(FromStruct from,
              int to)
  {

  }

template<class FromStruct>
void dconvert(FromStruct from,
              C to)
  {

  dconvert<FromStruct,int>(from, 5);

  }


// file main.cpp
#include <dconvert.h>
int main()
{
  ::dconvert(3,1); // ok
  C c;
  ::dconvert(3,c); // static assertion fails!
}
```

The main dconvert function is thought to assert if no other explicit conversion function is implemented.

What I don't understand is why the dconvert function overload is not being seen.

If I remove the lines:

```
C c;    
::dconvert(3,c);
```

or also if I keep the above ones and I remove

```
dconvert<FromStruct,int>(from, 5);
```

no assertion is thrown

Comment: You only have **overloads**, no **specializations**.

Comment: `template<class FromStruct, class ToStruct> void dconvert(FromStruct from, ToStruct to) = delete;` is an alternative to your `static_assert` (and I even think that your current template with `static_assert` is ill formed pedantically (a la `static_assert(false, "")`) BTW).

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I would prefer using a message, so I'll stick with the assertion. I like though the static_assert(false, "")

Comment: `static_assert(false, "")` makes program ill formed, but `static_assert(always_false<FromStruct>::value, "")` is fine. with (global scope) `template <typename T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};`.

Comment: that's right. There seem to be problems if I leave just false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in:

```
template<class FromStruct>
void dconvert(FromStruct from,
              C to)
```

you do this:

```
dconvert<FromStruct,int>(from, 5);
```

thus explicitly demanding to instantiate the first template (as it is the only one that has two template parameters) method. If you were to remove this demand, e.g. by allowing template type deduction to happen by leaving it:

```
dconvert(from, 5);
```

the code would compile without a problem.
Tested on clang6.0.

Comment: so you're saying that every time I don't use deduction, the first template, the one with the assertion is always instantiated. It still does not make so much sense to me

Comment: You explicitly ask for a template with two type parameters to be used. Hence, the only one fitting is the one with the static_static assert. You could as well call dconvert<FromStruct>(from, 5) and have it compile. But as soon as you ask for a template method with two template parameters there is only one that fits.